# Automatic User Authentication Framework for Controllers in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, before-filter

In rails I could do something like this to make sure a user is authenticated before accessing an action in the controller:

```
before_filter :checked_logged_in, :only => [:edit, :update]
```

I was wondering if ASP.NET MVC had something similar or if there was a framework out there that could essentially do something like the following:

For certain methods with actions that take a certain parameter, I want to point the action to a method, check to see if the user owns that object, and if so, proceed to the controller action.  If not, I want to redirect him to another action where I can show him he has invalid credentials.

So basically I am looking for a sort of "before_filter."  Anyone know of anything out there that can do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called Action filters in ASP.Net MVC, you can read more here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs.

Asp.net MVC comes with an Authorize filter to indicate actions that requiere the user to be authenticated.

Usage:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{

}
```

Comment: +1 and thanks for the link. I knew about them but couldn't remember what they where called.